# Ruby cancel object creation

Tags: ruby, object, constructor

How to cancel object creation if get wrong params?
Example:

```
class MyClass
    def initialize(a, b, c)
        @a = @b = @c = nil
        @a = a if a.is_a? Integer
        @b = b if b.is_a? String
        @c = c if c.is_a? Integer or c.is_a? Float
        return nil if @a == nil or @b == nil or @c == nil # doesn't works
    end
end
cl = MyClass.new('str', 'some', 1.0) # need cl to be nil because 1st param isn't Integer
```

Comment: Maybe use the factory method pattern so that an external method checks for valid parameters and if failed it returns nil instead an initialized object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's simple, just don't use the constructor. :)

```
class MyClass
  def initialize(a, b, c)
    @a, @b, @c = a, b, c
  end

  def self.fabricate(a, b, c)
    aa = a if a.is_a? Integer
    bb = b if b.is_a? String
    cc = c if c.is_a? Integer || c.is_a? Float
    return nil unless aa && bb && cc
    new(aa, bb, cc)
  end
end

cl = MyClass.fabricate('str', 'some', 1.0) # => nil
```

This patten is called Factory Method, by the way.

Comment: `self.fabricate` can be improved to this: `def self.fabricate(a, b, c);
    return unless a.is_a?(Integer) and b.is_a?(String) and c.is_a?(Integer) || c.is_a?(Float);
    new(a, b, c)
end`

Answer (score 1):

Unless you need some kind of silent failure mode for handling bad data, you may just simply want to raise errors and halt the program:

```
def initialize(a, b, c)
    @a = @b = @c = nil

    raise "First param to new is not an Integer" unless a.is_a? Integer
    @a = a

    raise "Second param to new is not a String" unless b.is_a? String
    @b = b

    raise "Third param to new is not an Integer or Float" unless c.is_a? Integer or c.is_a? Float
    @c = c
end
```

Whether you use this approach, or a factory method that passes over bad input depends on the kind of data you wish to work with.

Personally I would nearly always go with raising errors, unless I had a specific requirement to silently ignore bad data. But this is coding philosophy, and not necessarily the best answer for your problem.

Comment: + 1, but I’d make a case for always going with exceptions: if you really need to silently ignore bad input, wrapping the exception in a `rescue` clause is the way to go.